# Not able to print result inside output box

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, fetch

Please help me resolve the issue, below is my html code(css and javascript inbuilt).
issue 1. I am trying to print the results inside the output box, but instead the page is getting refreshed to create a blank page where the result is being printed.
issue 2. Also  I am using fetch API to post my request by still i had to use form tag, because when i am removing the form tags the post request is not getting triggered. Please help me resolve this. Thanks

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Helper function to validate URL format
    function isValidURL(url) {
        const urlPattern = /^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+[^\s]*$/i;
        return urlPattern.test(url.trim());
    }

    // Helper function to validate IP address format
    function isValidIPAddress(ip) {
        const ipPattern = /^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$|^(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{1,4}:){7}[a-fA-F0-9]{1,4}$/;
        return ipPattern.test(ip.trim());
    }


   // Update the handleFormSubmission function to directly construct FormData
  function handleFormSubmission(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get selected tests
    var selectedTests = [];
    var testsCheckbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][name=tests]:checked');
    testsCheckbox.forEach(function(checkbox) {
        selectedTests.push(checkbox.value);
    });

    // Get selected server
    var selectedServer = document.querySelector('select[name=server-select]').value;

    // Get test inputs
    var testInputs = document.querySelector('input[name=test-inputs]').value.split(',');

    // Validate test inputs
    var validInputs = testInputs.every(function(input) {
        return isValidURL(input) || isValidIPAddress(input);
    });

    if (!validInputs) {
        alert('Invalid input(s). Please enter valid URLs or IP addresses.');
        return;
    }

    // Construct data object
      var requestData = {
          tests: selectedTests.join(','),
          'server-select': selectedServer,
          'test-inputs': testInputs.join(',')
      };

    // Send POST request to the server using fetch API
      fetch('/run_group_tests', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(requestData)
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
          // Handle the response data
          updateOutputBox(data);
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
      return false;
    }


    // Function to update the output box with the test result
  function updateOutputBox(data) {
    var outputBox = document.getElementById('output-box');
    var testResultDiv = document.createElement('div');
    testResultDiv.classList.add('test-result');

    var heading = document.createElement('h4');
    heading.textContent = data.testName;
    testResultDiv.appendChild(heading);

    data.result.forEach((line) => {
        if (line.trim()) {
          const paragraph = document.createElement('p');
          paragraph.textContent = line;
          testResultDiv.appendChild(paragraph);
        }
    });

    outputBox.appendChild(testResultDiv);
  }

  document.getElementById('test-form').addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmission);

  // Function to download test results
  function downloadResults() {
    var results = document.getElementById('output-box').textContent;
    var blob = new Blob([results], { type: 'text/plain' });
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.download = 'test_results.txt';
    link.target = '_blank';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    link.remove();
  }

  document.getElementById('download-results-button').addEventListener('click', downloadResults);
});
```

```css
#test-form {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type="text"],
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

#output-container {
margin-top: 30px;
padding: 20px;
background-color: #FFF;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
border-radius: 8px;
}

.test-result {
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
border-radius: 8px;
}

.test-result h4 {
margin-top: 0;
font-weight: bold;
}

.test-result p {
margin: 0;
padding: 5px 0;
}

#output-box {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding: 10px;
height: 150px;
overflow-y: scroll;
background-color: #FFF;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
border-radius: 8px;
}

#output-box p {
margin: 0;
padding: 5px 0;
}

#download-results {
text-align: right;
margin-top: 20px;
}

#download-results button {
background-color: #007bff;
color: #FFF;
border: none;
padding: 10px 20px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.loading-state {
display: none;
font-size: 14px;
color: #007bff;
}
```

```html
<form id="test-form" method="POST" action="/run_group_tests";return false;>
  <div>
    <label for="server-select">Select ECN Server:</label><br>
    <select id="server-select" name ="server-select">
      <option value="xx,yy">xx</option>

      <option value="xx,yy">xx</option>

      <option value="xx,yy">xx</option>

      <option value="xx,yy">xx</option>

      <option value="xx,yy">xx</option>

      <option value="xx,yy">xx</option>

      <option value="xx,yy">xx</option>

      <option value="xx,yy">xx</option>

      <option value="xx,yy">xx</option>
      <!-- Add more options as needed -->
    </select>
    <br><br>

    <label>Select Tests to Run:</label><br>
    <label for="ping"><input type="checkbox" id="ping" name="tests" value="ping"> Ping</label><br>
    <label for="page-load"><input type="checkbox" id="page-load" name="tests" value="page-load"> Page Load</label><br>
    <label for="dns-lookup"><input type="checkbox" id="dns-lookup" name="tests" value="dns-lookup"> DNS Lookup</label><br>
    <label for="speed-test"><input type="checkbox" id="speed-test" name="tests" value="speed-test"> Speed Test</label><br>
    <label for="traceroute"><input type="checkbox" id="traceroute" name="tests" value="traceroute"> Traceroute</label><br>
    <label for="dhcp-lease"><input type="checkbox" id="dhcp-lease" name="tests" value="dhcp-lease"> DHCP Lease</label><br><br>

    <label for="test-inputs">Enter Test Inputs (separated by comma):</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="test-inputs" name="test-inputs"><br><br>


    <button id="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
    
    <div id="output-container" class="rounded-corners">
    <h2>Test Results</h2>
    <div id="output-box"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="download-results">
    <button id="download-results-button">Download Results</button>
    </div>
```

I have pasted my code above, i tried to use both AJAX and fetch, but still it is not working without form tag. Also i do not have an issue to use form tags along with fetch api or ajax, but i suspect because of the form tags the page is getting refreshed and my result is getting printed in a new page instead of output box.

Comment: Move this line `document.getElementById('test-form').addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmission);` into the scope of your `DOMContentLoaded` function body. That is, outside of that scope, due to asynchronous, it likely doesnt exist yet when you add it as listener.

Comment: I've edited your question so that your code is now a snippet that can be run directly from your question. Note that it has some invalid HTML which I did not make any corrections to. The closing `</form></div>` tags should be in the opposite order.

Comment: @GetSet Thanks for the suggestion, I made the changes. It is still giving the result after refreshing the page in a blank page and not inside the output box.

Comment: @ChrisBarr Thanks for your help, I have made the changes in the tag order as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your submit event is stopped, that is why you get a blank page. The following should work. I replaced the URL of the fetch request with a data URL just to test.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.forms['test-form'].addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmission);
  document.getElementById('download-results-button').addEventListener('click', downloadResults);
});

// Helper function to validate URL format
function isValidURL(url) {
  const urlPattern = /^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+[^\s]*$/i;
  return urlPattern.test(url.trim());
}

// Helper function to validate IP address format
function isValidIPAddress(ip) {
  const ipPattern = /^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$|^(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{1,4}:){7}[a-fA-F0-9]{1,4}$/;
  return ipPattern.test(ip.trim());
}


// Update the handleFormSubmission function to directly construct FormData
function handleFormSubmission(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let form = event.target;

  // Get selected tests
  var selectedTests = [...form.tests]
    .filter(input => input.checked)
    .map(input => input.value);

  // Get selected server
  var selectedServer = form['server-select'].value;

  // Get test inputs
  var testInputs = form['test-inputs'].value.split(',');

  // Validate test inputs
  var validInputs = testInputs.every(function(input) {
    return isValidURL(input) || isValidIPAddress(input);
  });

  if (!validInputs) {
    alert('Invalid input(s). Please enter valid URLs or IP addresses.');
    return;
  }

  // Construct data object
  var requestData = {
    tests: selectedTests.join(','),
    'server-select': selectedServer,
    'test-inputs': testInputs.join(',')
  };

  // Send POST request to the server using fetch API
  fetch('data:application/json,{\"result\":[\"test\"]}', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(requestData)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(updateOutputBox)
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}


// Function to update the output box with the test result
function updateOutputBox(data) {
  var outputBox = document.getElementById('output-box');
  var testResultDiv = document.createElement('div');
  testResultDiv.classList.add('test-result');

  var heading = document.createElement('h4');
  heading.textContent = data.testName;
  testResultDiv.appendChild(heading);

  data.result.forEach((line) => {
    if (line.trim()) {
      const paragraph = document.createElement('p');
      paragraph.textContent = line;
      testResultDiv.appendChild(paragraph);
    }
  });
  outputBox.appendChild(testResultDiv);
}

// Function to download test results
function downloadResults() {
  var results = document.getElementById('output-box').textContent;
  var blob = new Blob([results], {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.download = 'test_results.txt';
  link.target = '_blank';
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

```css
#test-form {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type="text"],
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

#output-container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.test-result {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.test-result h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.test-result p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

#output-box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#output-box p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

#download-results {
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#download-results button {
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #FFF;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.loading-state {
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #007bff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form name="test-form" method="POST" action="/run_group_tests">
    <div>
      <label for="server-select">Select ECN Server:</label><br>
      <select id="server-select" name="server-select">
        <option value="xx,yy">xx</option>
        <option value="xx,yy">xx</option>
        <option value="xx,yy">xx</option>
        <option value="xx,yy">xx</option>
        <option value="xx,yy">xx</option>
        <option value="xx,yy">xx</option>
        <option value="xx,yy">xx</option>
        <option value="xx,yy">xx</option>
        <option value="xx,yy">xx</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>

      <label>Select Tests to Run:</label><br>
      <label for="ping"><input type="checkbox" id="ping" name="tests" value="ping"> Ping</label><br>
      <label for="page-load"><input type="checkbox" id="page-load" name="tests" value="page-load"> Page Load</label><br>
      <label for="dns-lookup"><input type="checkbox" id="dns-lookup" name="tests" value="dns-lookup"> DNS Lookup</label><br>
      <label for="speed-test"><input type="checkbox" id="speed-test" name="tests" value="speed-test"> Speed Test</label><br>
      <label for="traceroute"><input type="checkbox" id="traceroute" name="tests" value="traceroute"> Traceroute</label><br>
      <label for="dhcp-lease"><input type="checkbox" id="dhcp-lease" name="tests" value="dhcp-lease"> DHCP Lease</label><br><br>

      <label for="test-inputs">Enter Test Inputs (separated by comma):</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="test-inputs" name="test-inputs"><br><br>


      <button id="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="output-container" class="rounded-corners">
  <h2>Test Results</h2>
  <div id="output-box"></div>
</div>

<div id="download-results">
  <button id="download-results-button">Download Results</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, i made the changes and tried, it is still sowing the results in a blank page. [Result page looks like this. it is my html page which which refreshes to open this blank page and then display the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNvWu.png)

Comment: @ProsenjitGhosh and you don't get any errors in the console when you load the page in the first place? Somehow the addeventlister code is not applied. Try to console.log something from within the DOMContentLoaded callback function.